# Amanhã é o dia!

Tags: debate

[image: Que tal?]

### Bom trabalho!

Vocês fizeram um excelente trabalho, plantando a semente de uma grande comunidade. Nós não poderíamos estar mais contentes com o resultado desse beta, e mal podemos esperar para mostrar a toda a comunidade de programadores de língua portuguesa o que vocês construíram.

### Como vai ser:

- Na madrugada desta terça-feira, nós vamos mudar a URL do site para `pt.stackoverflow.com`, conforme sugerido (pode parecer que não, mas nós ouvimos vocês ;).
- A partir daí, o `br.stackoverflow.com` vai redirecionar para o novo endereço.
- **Todo mundo vai ser deslogado do site**.
- Nós vamos remover a necessidade do link especial para acessar o site: todo mundo acessando o `pt.stackoverflow.com` ou `br.stackoverflow.com` vai poder se cadastrar ou logar.
- O site vai continuar em *Beta*, mas isso é devido ao trabalho de tradução que continua sendo feito. Para todos os efeitos, ele funcionará como nossos outros sites públicos (isso significa que algumas regras vão mudar, como o requisito mínimo de reputação para alguns privilégios).

### Como nós vamos promover o lançamento:

Na manhã desta quarta-feira (29 de Janeiro):

- Vão aparecer anúncios do site no Stack Overflow original para visitantes de todos os países de língua portuguesa.
- Vamos anunciar o lançamento em todos os nossos canais de mídia social (Twitter, Facebook, Google+).
- Ontem nós convidamos alguns dos programadores mais conhecidos no Brasil para participar da comunidade e escrever sobre suas impressões e experiências no dia do lançamento.
- Foi preparado um material básico para a imprensa de tecnologia no Brasil.

### Vem mais gente nova por aí -- Como recebê-los bem:

*(Você provavelmente já está cansado de saber essas coisas, mas nunca é demais lembrar que nosso site pode ser intimidador para um novato)*

Seja receptivo, ofereça ajuda e conselhos, edite ao invés de fechar (sempre que possível), essas coisas...

### Chame seus amigos, colegas de trabalho, família e divirta-se!

É hora de mostrar (e se gabar - só um pouquinho) do que vocês construíram!

Comment: Gabe-se, Gabe! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu estou me Gabeando pra isso desde o dia em que nasci!

Comment: Gabe Newell. (nossa, que ruim). No mais, curiosamente porcurei por "stack exchange brasil" anteontem, no Google, e vi um `br.stackoverflow.com`, mas não pude acessar. De qualquer forma, ótimo trabalho gente!

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Quem me dera... quem me dera... Mas o `br.stackoverflow.com` era nosso endereço antigo. Ele deve redirecionar para esse agora

Comment: Sim, Gabe, eu havia lido. Mas digo, coincidência, sabe? Juro, fui sem qualquer intenção e de repente, dois dias depois, lançam o site. É **muita** coincidência.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge A gente te ouviu ;)

Comment: @Gabe Daí sim! Pô, a comunidade brasileira de developers é legal! Eu era desmotivado ao ver o nível das perguntas no SO/US e comparar com um iMasters da vida no Brasil. Mas no SO/PT tá muito massa! Parabéns pela iniciativa de novo, Gabe, staff & contributors!

Comment: O nosso logo vai ser o do StackOverflow com cedilha?